# Laravel TokenMismatchException and dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload pictures via dropzone, but I get tokenmismatch error even tho I added csrf token everywhere needed, i'm getting quite desperate...

**My form**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'photo.upload', 'id' => 'hello', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'dropzone no-margin dz-clickable']) !!}
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**my script**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

Dropzone.options.hello = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    parallelUploads: 2, //limits number of files processed to reduce stress on server
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        // TODO: Image upload validation
        done();
    },
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {

        // Pass token. You can use the same method to pass any other values as well such as a id to associate the image with for example.
        formData.append("_token", $('input[name="_token"]').val() ); // Laravel expect the token post value to be named _token by default
    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, response) {
            // On successful upload do whatever :-)
        });
    }
};

// Manually init dropzone on our element.
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#hello", {
    url: $('#hello').attr('action')
});
```

**Request headers**

```
...
X-CSRF-Token:P4wc9NVVZJe1VjalPwO6d6WQXZ9eEqPd84ICpToG
...
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySKMUFNO6dbgzeQVK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

P4wc9NVVZJe1VjalPwO6d6WQXZ9eEqPd84ICpToG
------WebKitFormBoundarySKMUFNO6dbgzeQVK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

P4wc9NVVZJe1VjalPwO6d6WQXZ9eEqPd84ICpToG
------WebKitFormBoundarySKMUFNO6dbgzeQVK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screen Shot 2016-01-14 at 18.27.40.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarySKMUFNO6dbgzeQVK--
```

and When I look in the generated form THERE IS the csrf field

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="P4wc9NVVZJe1VjalPwO6d6WQXZ9eEqPd84ICpToG">
```

Do you have any idea why it's not working even when I put crsf token where I should?

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place hidden field within your form like as

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

You can make it different way by passing value of token using ajax call like as

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });
});
```

Comment: in the bottom of my question you can see, that in my generated form THERE IS <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="P4wc9NVVZJe1VjalPwO6d6WQXZ9eEqPd84ICpToG">

Comment: But I can't find it within your form you need to manually place it within  your `form` tag

Comment: I've updated my answer you can remove the first one and can use the second way around

Comment: Create something like `config.js` and call it before your `dropzone.js`

Comment: added your last update ot the config.js file called before dropzone.js and still not working.

 There is even X-CSRF-Token:P189MMHAU1YPDoqozMEaQKCdqFhzP3bHOlmVKygV  in my request header

Comment: Remove headers from your dropzone

Comment: I deleted the headers options from my dropzone settings and nothing, then I tried to just leave there empty headers object and still nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101191/discussion-between-jakub-kohout-and-uchiha).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new element which is kinda dirty. You can just include it inside your manually init of dropzone.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#hello", { 
            url: $('#hello').attr('action'),
            headers: {
               'x-csrf-token': document.querySelectorAll('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0].getAttributeNode('content').value,
            }
          });
```

For more detailed integration with laravel dropzone you can refer to this tutorial [Integrating Dropzone.js in Laravel 5 applications](http://anytch.com/integrating-dropzone-js-laravel-5-applications/)